# R join on like/grep condition

Tags: r, join, data.table, sql-like

I am looking for efficient way to join 2 data.frames/data.tables on character column using grep/like/stri_detect condition.

I am able to use sqldf package with join on like, but is pretty slow. On my 2 data.tables (5k rows, 20k rows) it takes about 60 seconds.

My second approach was to use CJ from data.table and after that stri_detect_fixed on 2 columns. This approach is faster(16 seconds) but I am afraid that with growing data it will be impossible to use( it significantly increase ram usage).

I also tried to do it in for loop but it was the slowest one.

Is there any way to do it faster especially in data.table ?

Below I paste my example :

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)
data1 <- data.table(col1 = paste0(c("asdasd asdasd 768jjhknmnmnj",
"78967ggh","kl00896754","kl008jku"),1:10000))

data2 <- data.table(col2 = paste0(c("mnj", "12345","kl008","lll1"), 1:10000))

system.time(join1 <- data.table(sqldf("select * 
           from data1 a inner join data2 b
                      on a.col1 like '%' || b.col2 || '%'", drv = "SQLite" )))



system.time(kartezjan <- CJ(col1 = data1[,c("col1"), with = F][[1]],
                            col2 = data2[,c("col2"), with = F][[1]],
 unique  = TRUE)[stri_detect_fixed(col1, col2, case_insensitive = FALSE)])
```

Comment: On my machine the sqldf code above took 89.02 seconds and it took 69.06 seconds using `on instr(a.col1, b.col2)` instead of `on ... like ...` and 409.35 seconds with data.table.  There is a `library(stringi)` call missing.

Comment: The results of your examples are different. Maybe you should give a simple example and explain what you want to happen in corner cases. (Value in col1 has no match, value in col2 has no match and multiple match possibilities ) Also it would be helpful to know if there are some constraints on the values.

Comment: I check it with `instr` but it was slower than with `on ... like ...`. Now I add library and change left join to inner join to make results the same.

Comment: In my case there could be values from data1 that can match multiple values in data2 and values in data2 that can match multiple values in data1

Comment: You need to compare all pairs so CJ is required, you can chunk by col1 to fit it into ram if required. The only speed up I see is to use `data1[["col1"]]` to access column as vector. It gave me 1 second speed up. There is an open FR for [Fuzzy join `FJ()` for unstructured search](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1431).

Comment: I got a slight speedup from 36 to 32 seconds on the `instr` version of the query (i.e. `on instr(a.col1, b.col2) > 0`) by setting an index on col2 with `setkey(data2, col2)`. Indexing doesn't help with the `like` version because the comparison string starts with a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

The `sqldf` approach is the fastest on my machine for your example data, but here is a faster `data.table` version in case it helps.

```
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

## Example data
v1 <- paste0(c("asdasd asdasd 768jjhknmnmnj", "78967ggh","kl00896754","kl008jku"),
    1:10000)
v2 <- paste0(c("mnj", "12345","kl008","lll1"), 1:10000)

data1 <- data.table(col1=v1, key="col1")
data2 <- data.table(col2=v2, key="col2")


## sqldf version
system.time(
  ans1 <- data.table(sqldf(
    "select * 
    from data1 a inner join data2 b
    on instr(a.col1, b.col2)", drv="SQLite"))
  )

##    user  system elapsed 
##  17.579   0.036  17.654 


## parallelized data.table version
suppressMessages(library(foreach)); suppressMessages(library(doParallel))
cores <- detectCores() ## I've got 4...
clust <- makeForkCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(clust)

system.time({
  batches <- cores
  data2[, group:=sort(rep_len(1:batches, nrow(data2)))]
  ans2 <- foreach(
    i=1:batches, .combine=function(...) rbindlist(list(...)),
    .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
      CJ(col1=data1[, col1], col2=data2[group==i, col2])[,
        alike:=col1 %like% col2, by=col2][
          alike==TRUE][, alike:=NULL][]          
    }
})

##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.185   0.229  30.295 

stopCluster(clust)
stopImplicitCluster()
```

I'm running this on OSX--you may need to tweak the parallelization code for other operating systems.  Also, if your actual data is bigger and you're running out of memory, you can try larger `batches` values.

Comment: I ran this recently using DuckDB, and it's quite a bit faster than sqldf (which uses SQLite).